# Windows CMD: How do I parse a JSON response and store it in environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, cmd, aws-cli

I am not a Windows user and am struggling to get through a relatively simple task.

This is my batch script:

```
set ProfileName=default
set /p MfaTokenCode=Enter the MFA token code: 
set MfaDeviceArn=arn:aws:iam::12345678:mfa/some-mfa

for /f "usebackq delims=," %%a in (`
aws sts get-session-token --serial-number %MfaDeviceArn% --token-code %MfaTokenCode% --duration-seconds 3600 --output json --query "Credentials" --profile %ProfileName%
`) do set Credentials=%%a
```

The output of the aws sts command is something like:

```
{
  "AccessKeyId": "ghhjjj",
  "SecretAccessKey": "123",
  "SessionToken": "12lllllllnk3",
  "Expiration": "2023-04-04T11:02:17+00:00"
}
```

What I need now is store the values into environment variables but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

I need to store:

- environment variable name: AccessKeyId, value: ghhjjj
- environment variable name: SecretAccessKey, value: 123
- etc

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try PowerShell to set the vars: ...
`) do set Credentials=%%a

for /f "usebackq tokens=2,4 delims=:," %%a in (`powershell -Command "(ConvertFrom-Json '%Credentials%') | Select-Object AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey"`) do (
    set "AccessKeyId=%%a"
    set "SecretAccessKey=%%b"
)

echo AccessKeyId=%AccessKeyId%
echo SecretAccessKey=%SecretAccessKey%

Comment: Any reason you aren't using powershell?

Comment: check if [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/36ff0d6e101716b91c94ea29e10d0c471387d99c/hybrids/jscript/jsonextractor.bat) will be useful for you.

Comment: Be aware of potentially helpful third-party tools such as [awsdo](https://github.com/k1LoW/awsdo) and [sts2credentials](https://github.com/ynouri/sts2credentials).

Comment: Of course, if you wanted to stick with a batch file, use `text` as the `output` format, not `json`, and parse the multiline tab delimited strings with a `For /F` loop instead.

Comment: Example: ```For /F "Tokens=1,*" %%G In ('aws sts get-session-token --serial-number %MfaDeviceArn% --token-code %MfaTokenCode% --duration-seconds 3600 --output text --query "Credentials" --profile %ProfileName%') Do Set "%%~G=%%~H"```.